# Pthreads aren't performing their functions synchronously

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, mutex, synchronous

So I'm trying to finish an assignment for my parallel class, and it involves using Pthreads to sum some numbers.

I have a sum function to which I pass a struct:

```
void *partition(void* p){
    ThreadData *a=malloc(sizeof(ThreadData));
    a=(ThreadData*)p;

    int i = a->pid;

    int sum=0;

    int size = a->rows*a->cols;
    int row=a->pid/a->cols;
    int col=a->pid%a->cols;

    int partition_size = ((size / processors)+1);

    for(i;i<partition_size*processors;i+=processors){

        col = i%a->cols;
        row = i/a->cols;

        if (i<=size-1){
            sum+= matrix[row][col]+1;
            //printf("[%d][%d]%d +",row,col,matrix[row][col]);
        }


    }

    a->localsum=sum;
    printf("function sum: %d\n",sum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and in my main method I have the following

```
int main(){


    int totalsum=0;
    void *status;
    ThreadData *g;
    g=malloc(processors*( sizeof(ThreadData)));
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<processors;i++){
        g[i].rows=rows;
        g[i].cols=cols;
        g[i].pid=i;
        g[i].localsum=0;
    }

    fillMatrix(rows, cols);

    pthread_t tid[processors];

    i;

    for(i=0;i<processors;i++){
        pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,partition,(void *)&g[i]);
        sleep(1);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mVar);
        totalsum+=g[i].localsum;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mVar);

    }
    for(i=0;i<processors;i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }

    printf("The sum of your Matrix is %d",totalsum);
}
```

for 3 processors on a 4x4 matrix I get the following output

```
function sum: 51
function sum: 40
function sum: 45
The sum of your Matrix is 136
```

So as you can see, in order to produce the desired result, I'm using `sleep(1);` but having the program wait a whole second before moving on totally defeats the purpose of multi-threading for parallel computing.  It also makes he use of the mutual exclusion locks pointless, I can literally comment them out and the program functions the same.

From what I've seen in tutorials around the web, this is the way a lot of people have written their code, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

So how can I rewrite this code same result without using `sleep();`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to wait for the threads to finish (join them) before trying to use their results.

Comment: I tried joining them inside the same for loop as the creates but it did not seem to work

Comment: That wouldn't make sense either. Think about it. You create the threads. Let them all run. Then you wait for all of them to finish. Two loops  .

Comment: @Csteele5 You know that the computer does things in the order you tell it to, right? So if you had create and join in one loop, then it would be: Create thread 1, wait for thread 1 to finish, create thread 2, wait for thread 2 to finish, .... whereas you want: create thread 1, create thread 2, ..., wait for thread 1 to finish, wait for thread 2 to finish, ...

Comment: So more like I have it in the post then... It's just weird cause if I put print statements there with the join they work out of order.... I can post a picture if you'd like... And in fact many functions can act asynchronously. So what I'm asking here is how exactly to get them to behave in a synchronous way, even though they appeared to be mapped as such.

Comment: First your program has memory leak.  In `partition(...)`, you allocate memory for variable `a`, but you then point `a` to `p`.  The memory allocated to `a` is not released.  Back to your question, you can return the sum of each thread via `pthread_exit()`, and then get the result from `pthread_join()`.

Comment: You can also calculate the total in the `for` loop for `pthread_join` instead of in that for `pthread_create`.